# How to validate dynamic inputs in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, validation

I've tried some of the solutions in the internet but they're using different version of laravel. I'm using laravel 5.1 here. The problem is I can't validate dynamic inputs using `$this->validate()`. Please see my code below:

**Controller**

```
public function postTake(Request $request){

  $this->validate($request, [
    'true_false' => 'required',
    'multiple_choice' => 'required',
    'short_answer' => 'required'
  ]);

}
```

**View**

```
Answer1
<input type="text" name="true_false[]"><br>

Answer2
<input type="text" name="true_false[]"><br>

Answer3
<input type="text" name="true_false[]"><br>

Answer4
<input type="text" name="true_false[]"><br>

Answer5
<input type="text" name="true_false[]"><br>

Answer6
<input type="text" name="multiple_choice[]"><br>

Answer7
<input type="text" name="short_answer[]">
```

This will only validate the first `true_false[]` input.

**This question have no answer yet, since I'm using LARAVEL 5.1 Version**

Comment: Hi @vijaykumar I also want to check if the input is exists or not before the validation. Sorry, please see the update

Comment: @Jonjie I've added my answer, have a look.

Comment: you didn't specify proper validation for `true_false` ? do you want required all or at least one ?

Comment: Hi @C2486 all is required.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

The answer @jeuneGuerrier added doesn't work in laravel 5.1

Since, array input validation is introduced in laravel 5.2 and later versions so you need to make custom request class for array input validation.

You can make custom request like this

```
php artisan make:request ArrayInputRequest
```

Now a file `app/Http/Requests/ArrayInputRequest.php` is created where you have to add validation logic.

Your `ArrayInputRequest.php` should look something like this,

```
public function authorize()
{
   return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'true_false' => 'required',
        'multiple_choice' => 'required',
        'short_answer' => 'required',
    ];

    foreach($this->request->get('true_false') as $key => $val)
    {
       $rules['true_false.'.$key] = 'required';
    }

    foreach($this->request->get('multiple_choice') as $key => $val)
    {
       $rules['multiple_choice.'.$key] = 'required';
    }

    foreach($this->request->get('short_answer') as $key => $val)
    {
       $rules['short_answer.'.$key] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}

public function messages()
{
 // Write error messages here
}
```

Now, your controller function should like,

```
public function postTake(ArrayInputRequest $request){

}
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: Hi Sagar. How can I use those methods in my controller?

Comment: @Jonjie just mention the request class as I've mentioned at last of my answer, those are called automatically as you send the form request.

Comment: I'll try this, but. what if the input `true_false[]` is not exists? and other inputs is there? Please see my updates.

Comment: @Jonjie the first rule will check that if not exist validation is failed. and then do same for other inputs as well.

Comment: I mean, no input that has a name of `true_false`, because it is dynamic, and sometimes, no `true_false` included, sometimes there is.

Comment: @Jonjie If no input named `true_false` is included then validation should be failed or not ?

Comment: The validations should NOT failed because there is at least one question in my form, it could be `true_false`, `multiple_choice`, or `short_answer`.

Comment: @Jonjie If so then use `required_with` validation rule so that values inside array are validated only if array exists.

Comment: I'll try it. Please wait for my response soon.

Comment: @Jonjie Okay if solved let me know I'll feel  better :D :D

Comment: I got an error in `ArrayInputRequest`, `ErrorException in ArrayInputRequest.php line 19: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @Jonjie To be precise which foreach line shows error ?

Comment: The first foreach, `foreach($this->request->get('true_false') as $key => $val)
    {
       $rules['true_false.'.$key] = 'required';
    }`

Comment: @Jonjie it's difficult to understand whats wrong. what are the inputs passed in the request ?

Comment: `true_false[]` inputs.

Comment: I've also tried to use `required_with`, but it has the same error.

Comment: @Jonjie I think it should work. I am unable to understand exact problem.

Comment: @Jonjie Can you add what's on `$request->all();`

Comment: Is it required to use `ArrayInputRequest $request`, because I used `ArrayInputRequest $array_request`

Comment: I'm currently using the `Request $request` in my method. How can I use the `ArrayInputRequest` without removing the `Request $request`?

Comment: @Jonjie Just use `ArrayInputRequest $request` in the controller function.

Comment: Is it fine to just use the `ArrayInputRequest $request` even if I've already used `Request $request` on different inputs, like `student_name`?

Comment: @Jonjie No, only for that particular case. Otherwise you have to change code

Comment: Is it fine to just use the `ArrayInputRequest $request` even if I've already used `Request $request` on different inputs, like `student_name` on the same form?

Comment: @Jonjie I'm confused now what you are trying to say :D :D

Comment: Ooh, I'm sorry for confusion. My `postTake()` is now look something like this: `public function postTake(Request $request, ArrayInputRequest $array_request){ $request->input('student_name') }` .

Comment: Now remove `Request $request` from the function

Comment: So now, I should use `ArrayInputRequest $request` instead? Will this affect the other `$request` variables?

Comment: @Jonjie Will not affect

Comment: I have the same error.

Comment: @Jonjie It's difficult to say anything right now because i don't know where the problem is

Comment: Please ask what info you need, so I can provide.

Comment: @Jonjie It's really difficult for you to add all things  as well If I am able to view your model view controller and all things it would be easier but it's completely difficult thing. I'm sorry

Comment: @Jonjie Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165715/discussion-between-sagar-gautam-and-jonjie).

Comment: @Jonjie I'm sorry I was out for a while please comeback in chat.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question completly but i assume this is what you are looking for

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'true_false' => 'required|array',
    'true_false.*' => 'required|boolean',
    'multiple_choice' => 'required|array',
    'multiple_choice.*' => 'required|boolean', 
    'short_answer' => 'required|array',
    'short_answer.*' => 'required|boolean', 
  ]);
```

[Ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-array)

Sorry 5.1 not supporting array input you have do something like this

```
 $rules = [
    'true_false' => 'required|max:255',
  ];

  foreach($this->request->get('true_false') as $key => $val)
  {
    $rules['true_false.'.$key] = 'required';
  }

  return $rules;
```

Comment: Will this work for laravel **5.1**?

Comment: Yes try once @Jonjie

Comment: @vijaykumar I don't think so, even in official docs array input validation is not mentioned in laravel 5.1

Comment: @vijaykumar Thats good which will check input must be array but not elements inside the array.  use of dot notation is not mentioned in 5.1 or lower version I think.

Comment: Yes @SagarGautam .Sorry i didn't check that update my answer.

Comment: @vijaykumar it's okay, thats why i've added validation with custom request class in my answer.